# UITableView cell space on right side

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, xcode5

I am building an app with `UITableView` in a `UIView` & i want to remove all extra space around `UITableView` & i manage to remove margin from left side of `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell` but now i am having weird space on right side when i select a row here is my code to remove margin from left.

```
self.mytableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 0);
```

And this is what is happining

[image]

Please help me remove this space from right when row is selected.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase the width of your tablview in stroyboard

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially pulled the content off screen by 15, but since the width is still the same you'll have to add 15 to it.

Try this;

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect frame = self.mytableview.frame;
    [self.mytableview setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width+15, frame.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this it's

```
myTableView=[[UITableView alloc]init];
myTableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.hight);
```

it's taken max width of you mobile.If you increase it's not fixed ever mobile

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem.

Turns out the cause was the ViewController -> Simulated Size.
Changed it from freeform to fixed.

Hope it helps someone else.